# how to read the value of selecting cell of UITableVIew in objective c

Tags: iphone, xcode

Hello i am new in objective c. i have used sqlite database and showing table data into UITableVIew now i want to show this data like which cell is select that data will show at a label. more that tableview data is showing after clicking a button now after selecting the cell - tableview will be off and cell data will show  at lavel in another from where tableview is calling.

Answer (score 1):

- (NSIndexPath *)indexPathForSelectedRow

would give u the cell selected..